# MySQL stored function won't compile with MODIFIES SQL DATA

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

If I compile the stored function below in MySQL (using the MySQL Workbench 8.0), I get the message:

> ERROR 1418: This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS
>   SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled...

However, if I change `MODIFIES SQL DATA` to `READS SQL DATA`, the function compiles just fine. The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) says:

> MODIFIES SQL DATA indicates that the routine contains statements that
>   may write data (for example, INSERT or DELETE).

So why is `MODIFIES SQL DATA` not accepted? I understand these characteristics are "advisory only", but I'd still like to use the correct characteristic.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DoSomething(employeeName VARCHAR(30)) RETURNS int(11)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
   DECLARE income INT;

   SELECT Salary
   INTO income
   FROM Employee
   WHERE Name = employeeName;

   UPDATE Employee
   SET Salary = 300
   WHERE Name = employeeName;

   IF income < 5000 THEN
      RETURN 0;
   ELSE
      RETURN (income - 5000) * 0.1;
   END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0.19 and Workbench it is enough to use DETERMINISTIC

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the function options like DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL
or READS SQL DATA doesn't decide nothing, it only indicates, that you have make a decision about its security. 
Functions that have NO SQL or READS SQL DATA clearly tell MySQL that there are no data manipulation inside and they are secure.

By using DETERMINISTIC you tell mysql that it is safe to run this function, which does manipulate data inside..

See the [mysql explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-logging.html), which reads:

> By default, for a CREATE FUNCTION statement to be accepted, at least
>   one of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA must be specified
>   explicitly.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `DoSomething`(employeeName VARCHAR(30)) RETURNS int
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   DECLARE income INT;

   SELECT Salary
   INTO income
   FROM Employee
   WHERE Name = employeeName;

   UPDATE Employee
   SET Salary = 300
   WHERE Name = employeeName;

   IF income < 5000 THEN
      RETURN 0;
   ELSE
      RETURN (income - 5000) * 0.1;
   END IF;
END
```

Updates employee

Comment: DETERMINISTIC indicates the function produces the same result for the same input parameters. This is definitely not the case as the table values can change. However, MySQL Workbench fails to compile when using NOT DETERMINISTIC.

Comment: Ok i should have written more information. Function return only values, with DETERMINSTIC you indicate to mysql that your function is **safe**, There are mayn things you can't use in functions for security reasons like stetements. So if you want top update empoyee in your fuctions, put it in DETERMINISTIC as I wrote.